# Work of a vector field along a curve

Tags: analysis, vector-fields

I'm having doubts about this exercise:

> Evaluate the work of the following field:
> $$F(x,y) = (\cos(y+2) + 1, -x\sin(y+2)-2) $$
> along the curve:
> $$
> \begin{split} 
> \delta &:[0, 3\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^2 \\ 
> t &\mapsto (t\cos(t), t\sin(t))
> \end{split}
> $$
> I've tried to solve it using this:
> $$ L_{\delta}(F) = \int_0^{3\pi}{F(\delta(t))\  \cdot \ \delta'(t) \ dt}$$
> but the resulting integral looks a bit too hard to evaluate by hand so I'm wondering if i used the wrong formula but i can't seem to find another method.
> Thanks.

Comment: Look fine to me

Comment: @DARK in the integral i'll have cos(tsint+2) and more, is that fine to solve by hand? I have no idea how to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some thinking I worked out the solution. I leave it here for anyone to use.

The tricky part was to understand that i needed to use the work of conservative fields along a curve. The formula states:
$$ L_{\delta}(F) = \int_{\delta}F\cdot d\delta = U(\delta(b))-U(\delta(a))$$
Using this i could easily evaluate the field potential
$$ U(x,y) = x\cos(y+2)+x-2y$$
And use the formula to obtain as following
$$L_{\delta}(F) = \int_{\delta}F\cdot d\delta = U(\delta(b))-U(\delta(a)) = U(-3\pi,0)-U(0,0) = -3\pi(1+\cos(2))$$

Comment: The vector field is not conservative. Perhaps you typed it incorrectly.

Comment: I agree with your work. Fine solution!

Comment: Looks [right](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=grad%28x%5Ccos%28y%2B2%29%2Bx-2y%29).

Comment: seems like your initial vector field was a typo then

Comment: @CaptainChicky Aha. To be precise: $F(x,y) = (\cos(y+2) + 1, -\color{red}{x}\sin(y+2)-2)$ is conservative while OP's initial $F(x,y) = (\cos(y+2) + 1, -\sin(y+2)-2)$ was not. Nothing escapes Ted Shifrin.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the formula for work when given a vector field and path is just a line integral, so your formula is not wrong by any means.

Anyhow let's see,

so we have
$$\vec{F} = \langle \cos(y+2)+1, -\sin(y+2)-2 \rangle,\qquad \vec{\delta} = \langle t\cos(t), t\sin(t)\rangle$$
$$\implies \vec{F}(\vec{\delta}) = \langle \cos(t\sin(t)+2)+1, -\sin(t\sin(t)+2)-2 \rangle$$

We also have
$$\vec{\delta}\,' = \langle \cos(t)-t\sin(t), \sin(t)+t\cos(t)\rangle$$

So $$\vec{F}(\vec{\delta}) \cdot \vec{\delta}\,'= -t\sin(t)-2\sin(t)-t\sin(t+t\sin(t)+2) - 2t\cos(t)+\cos(t)+\cos(t+t\sin(t)+2)$$

The antiderivative of this function is not expressible in terms of frequently used functions (from the existence of the nested cosine and sine terms), so either

- You were supposed to solve this integral numerically
- The problem was given wrong/you misread the problem

Numerically the work done is around [-2.5](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20-%28-1%20%2B%202%20t%29%20cos%28t%29%20%2B%20cos%282%20%2B%20t%20%2B%20t%20sin%28t%29%29%20-%20%282%20%2B%20t%29%20sin%28t%29%20-%20t%20sin%282%20%2B%20t%20%2B%20t%20sin%28t%29%29%20from%200%20to%203pi).